# How to modify Apps Script for Google Sheets to move specific cell from a row into another Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

The script, that I will post below, allows me to use a check box to move an entire row from one sheet to another in the same workbook. Everything works (I was following a YouTube tutorial), but it moves the entire row of data. Instead, I need it to move only data from specific columns, i.e. move the info from column A to C or move the info from column A and column K. I know this might be a simple question, but I just don't know which line to modify and how to modify it so that the script only pulls the info from specific columns within the row to move to the other sheet.

```
function onEdit() {
 

  var mainSheet = "MLReachout";
  var sheetToMoveTheRow = "MLReplied";
 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  if(sheet.getName() == "MLReachOut" && range.getColumn() == 11 && range.getValue() == true) {
    var row = range.getRow();
    var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MLReplied");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    sheet.deleteRow(row);
  } else if(sheet.getName() == "MLReplied" && range.getColumn() == 11 && range.getValue() == false) {
    var row = range.getRow();
    var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MLReachOut");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    sheet.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

I tried to modify the line "var row = range.getRow()" by putting column letters in the parenthesis but it didn't do anything, not only did it not move the info from those specific columns but it no longer moved the entire row. It just no longer did anything.

Comment: Sheet:"MLReachout" inconsistently referenced. `var mainSheet = "MLReachout";` vs `if(sheet.getName() == "MLReachOut"...`

Comment: You need to read up on `Event Objects` [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). For `onEdit`, Event objects would give you the range, value, row, column  and many more - no guessing.

Comment: Code works fine for me.